# What do 1, 2, 3 represent in $\operatorname{U}(1)+\operatorname{SU}(2)+\operatorname{SU}(3)$?

Tags: lie-groups

What do 1, 2, 3 represent in $\operatorname{U}(1)+\operatorname{SU}(2)+\operatorname{SU}(3)$?
If they are dimensions, how they can be added? or plus has another meaning?

Comment: $U(n)$ is the unitary group of $n\times n$ matrices.  And $SU(n)$ is the special unitary group of $n\times n$ matrices.  Should the + be a $\times$?

Comment: Are you talking about Lie groups or Lie algebras?

Comment: i guess Lie groups as i am not sure whether it is in gauge theory, how dimension 1x1 times 2x2 times 3x3? or U is matrix 1x2 times SU 2x3 times SU 3x3?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 7):

They indicate the dimension of the complex vector space on which the group acts. The [unitary group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_group) $\text{U}(n)$ and the [special unitary group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_unitary_group) $\text{SU}(n)$ both act on $\mathbb{C}^n$. The "plus" actually indicates the [direct product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_product) $G \times H$ of groups $G, H$, which is the set of pairs $(g, h), g \in G, h \in H$ under pointwise multiplication. This is sometimes conflated with the [direct sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum), but in my opinion it is better to avoid the sum notation for non-abelian groups.

**Edit:** Ah, you might be talking about the [Lie algebras](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra) $\mathfrak{u}(n), \mathfrak{su}(n)$, in which case the answer is still that $n$ is the dimension of the complex vector space on which the Lie algebra acts, except that the notion of an action is different.

Comment: Generally, lower case letters indicate the Lie algebras.  Of course, this doesn't really effect the content of what you wrote, but I would add that + or $\oplus$ is often used as the direct sum operation for lie algebras (though I agree with avoiding the sum notation for non-abelian groups!).  *edit* - I just noticed this is tagged Lie-groups and not Lie-algebras.  Now I'm just really confused ;-)